# git commit auto add new folders or files?

Tags: git

Is it possible to have `git commit` also add new files and directories?

It seems a lot of needless typing in the long run to have to type `git add .` then `git commit`

(That, and I have a tendency to often forget to call `git add .` resulting in versions with missing directories and such)

Comment: if you use a IDE from Jetbrais you will have a list of unversioned files. You will still have to add and commit, but atleast you have a visual list.

Comment: would `git commit -a` do what you need?

Comment: git commit -a does not seem to stage the new files.. i've been using that but the new directories and files were not added automatically

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate - but Jetbrains does not support very many languages, so it would be nice if there were some one line terminal command for this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as I am informed right there is no such command (It could be dangerous when you have debug-files containing passwords), but if you want to simulate you could add this alias to your git config:

```
git config --global alias.commitx "!git add . && git commit"
```

Using `git commitx` will now run `git add .` followed by `git commit`, so you can do

```
git commitx -m "testing commitx on new unstaged files"
```

Comment: this seems like it's the trick... do i just type this into the terminal to set it up: `git config alias.commitx=!git add . && git commit -a -m`

Comment: @ina: The command would be `git config --global alias.commitx '!git add . && git commit -a -m'` - you have to quote the command to keep bash from interpreting it, and `git config` (the command) doesn't use `=` in its syntax, just `<config-parameter> <value>` as separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks guys - this is very helpful... collectively, among me + the users who google this up, you've probably saved gazillions of microseconds already! :-)