# What is the meaning of the "bang" or "!" before the git command?

Tags: terminal, git-add, git, git-alias

As you can see from this excerpt, there is a "!" before the git command. What's the point?

```
[alias]
commitx = !git add . && git commit
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956546/1354543

I understand aliases and what the command itself is doing, but not the point of the "!" before the git command.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `!` means "run the following as commands to the shell", so in this case the alias `git commitx` expands to the equivalent of running `git add . && git commit` (which is a terrible terrible idea)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer! Also agree it is a bad idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

An important aspect of `!` not covered by the accepted answer is that for the shell command, the working directory is set to the top level of the working copy.  Therefore, `git commitx` would stage then commit all new and changed files in the working copy, while running `git add . && git commit` manually would stage then commit all new and changed files in the current directory.

Comment: Is there anyway to achive the same shell execution, but without changing working dir to top level?

Comment: @Jarl Not that I know of