# In Git, what does `--` (dash dash) mean?

Tags: git

When reading the man pages for Git commands, you will often see an optional `--` (dash dash). In my experience, the `--` is not necessary and makes no difference. When do you need it? What does it mean in general, given that it appears in so many commands?

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This question asks for a conceptual understanding of the double-dash across all git commands.  The linked question asks only about `git checkout`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The double dash `--` in git means different things to different commands, but in general it separates options from parameters.

In **git** specifically, the meaning of `--` depends on which subcommand you are using it with. It usually separates subcommand arguments (like the branch name in `git checkout`) from revisions or filenames.  Sometimes it is completely optional and used only to prevent an unusual filename from being interpreted as program options.

For Example

- `git checkout`.  To check out a "commit" (referred to as "tree-ish" in the manual, because you can actually specify a range of object types) you use

  `git checkout <commit>`

  To refine the checkout to just a file or two, use `--` to separate the "tree-ish" parameters from the "filenames" you wish to check out.
- `git commit`.   To commit whatever is in the "index" (ie, what you have staged via `git add`, simply issue the `git commit` command.

  `git commit` [-m message]

  To ignore whatever you have added via `git add` and commit the changes in a specific file, use
  `git commit -- <filename>`
- `git add`.  To commit a file whose name begins with a `-` or a `--`, you must tell git add to stop reading parameters, and start reading filenames; `--` does that.

  `git add -- -sample.txt`
- `git log`.  To see the commit history restricted to only commits affecting a file use

  `git log -- <filename>`

You need to check the man pages for any git command you use if you need to understand its specific meaning.

Comment: Funny. I got here from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff and among all the examples listed git-diff is missing :) Got the point though, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> This question asks for a conceptual understanding of the double-dash across all git commands.

The double-dash, which signals the end of options, has been recognized as "not enough" for Git.

With Git 2.24 (Q3 2019), the command line parser learned the "`--end-of-options`" notation:

The standard convention for scripters to have hardcoded set of options first on the command line, and force the command to treat end-user input as non-options, has been to **use "`--`" as the delimiter, but that would not work for commands that use "`--`" as a delimiter between revs and pathspec.**

See [commit 67feca3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67feca3b1c45a51b204253039139b46cc07e145f), [commit 51b4594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51b4594b4024d5cb2b4ace36ff932affa31c03f4), [commit 19e8789](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19e8789b236dfe33667747d5523d6689bb59b5ef) (06 Aug 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a12f89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a12f89865236789b5723277bb6809e92ce68f54), 09 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `revision`: allow `--end-of-options` to end option parsing

> There's currently no robust way to tell Git that a particular option is meant to be a revision, and not an option.
> So if you have a branch "`refs/heads/--foo`", you cannot just say:
>
> ```
> git rev-list --foo
> ```
>
> You can say:
>
> ```
> git rev-list refs/heads/--foo
> ```
>
> But that breaks down if you don't know the refname, and in particular if you're a script passing along a value from elsewhere.
> In most programs, you can use "`--`" to end option parsing, like this:
>
> ```
> some-prog -- "$revision"
> ```
>
> **But that doesn't work for the revision parser, because "`--`" is already meaningful there: it separates revisions from pathspecs.**
> So we need some other marker to separate options from revisions.
>
> This patch introduces "`--end-of-options`", which serves that purpose:
>
> ```
> git rev-list --oneline --end-of-options "$revision"
> ```
>
> will work regardless of what's in "$revision" (well, if you say "`--`" it may fail, but it won't do something dangerous, like triggering an unexpected option).
>
> The name is verbose, but that's probably a good thing; this is meant to be used for scripted invocations where readability is more important than terseness.
>
> One alternative would be to introduce an explicit option to mark a revision, like:
>
> ```
> git rev-list --oneline --revision="$revision"
> ```
>
> That's slightly *more* informative than this commit (because it makes even something silly like "--" unambiguous). But the pattern of using a separator like "`--`" is well established in git and in other commands, and it makes some scripting tasks simpler like:
>
> ```
> git rev-list --end-of-options "$@"
> ```

---

> ### parse-options: allow `--end-of-options` as a synonym for "--"

> The revision option parser recently learned about `--end-of-options`, but that's not quite enough for all callers.
> Some of them, like `git-log`, pick out some options using `parse_options()`, and then feed the remainder to `setup_revisions()`.
> For those cases we need to stop `parse_options()` from finding more options when it sees `--end-of-options`, and to retain that option in `argv` so that `setup_revisions()` can see it as well.
>
> Let's handle this the same as we do "`--`". We can even piggy-back on the
> handling of `PARSE_OPT_KEEP_DASHDASH`, because any caller that wants to
> retain one will want to retain the other.

Example:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/--source HEAD &&\
git log --end-of-options --source
```

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0dd171f0bc59f8f1a5bb6741276c35caf2d4117d/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))</sup> learned the "`--end-of-options`" to help scripts to safely take a parameter that is supposed to be a revision, e.g. "[`git rev-parse --verify -q --end-of-options $rev`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0dd171f0bc59f8f1a5bb6741276c35caf2d4117d/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L98)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-))</sup>".

See [commit 3a1f91c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a1f91cfd9633a4f59e0534fa5ba076e031a78ed), [commit 9033add](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9033addfa6a910325fbe9619dc623c17e989261c), [commit e05e2ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e05e2ae8fe6e5d83254c27664c66bc47b270b6d2) (10 Nov 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0dd171f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dd171f0bc59f8f1a5bb6741276c35caf2d4117d), 21 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a1f91cfd9633a4f59e0534fa5ba076e031a78ed): handle `--end-of-options`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We taught rev-list a new way to separate options from revisions in [19e8789b23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19e8789b236dfe33667747d5523d6689bb59b5ef) ("`revision`: allow --end-of-options to end option parsing", 2019-08-06, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a12f89865236789b5723277bb6809e92ce68f54) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1d4a28250629ae469fc5dd59ab843cb2fd68e12)), but `rev-parse` uses its own parser.
> It should know about `--end-of-options` not only for consistency, but because it may be presented with similarly ambiguous cases. E.g., if a caller does:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse "$rev" -- "$path"
> ```
>
> to parse an untrusted input, then it will get confused if `$rev` contains an option-like string like "`--local-env-vars`".
> Or even "`--not-real`", which we'd keep as an option to pass along to rev-list.
>
> Or even more importantly:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --verify "$rev"
> ```
>
> can be confused by options, even though its purpose is safely parsing untrusted input.
> On the plus side, it will always fail the `--verify` part, as it will not have parsed a revision, so the caller will generally "fail closed" rather than continue to use the untrusted string.
> But it will still trigger whatever option was in "`$rev`"; this should be mostly harmless, since rev-parse options are all read-only, but I didn't carefully audit all paths.
>
> This patch lets callers write:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --end-of-options "$rev" -- "$path"
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --verify --end-of-options "$rev"
> ```
>
> which will both treat "`$rev`" always as a revision parameter.
> The latter is a bit clunky. It would be nicer if we had defined "`--verify`" to require that its next argument be the revision.
> But we have not historically done so, and:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --verify -q "$rev"
> ```
>
> does currently work. I added a test here to confirm that we didn't break that.
>
> A few implementation notes:
>
> - We don't have to re-indent the main option-parsing block, because we can combine our "did we see end of options" check with "does it start with a dash". The exception is the pre-setup options, which need their own block.
> - We do however have to pull the "`--`" parsing out of the "does it start with dash" block, because we want to parse it even if we've seen `--end-of-options`.
> - We'll leave "`--end-of-options`" in the output. This is probably not technically necessary, as a careful caller will do:
>
>   git rev-parse --end-of-options $revs -- $paths
>
> and anything in $revs will be resolved to an object id.
> However, it does help a slightly less careful caller like:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --end-of-options $revs_or_paths
> ```
>
> where a path "`--foo`" will remain in the output as long as it also exists on disk.
> In that case, it's helpful to retain `--end-of-options` to get passed along to rev-list, as it would otherwise see just "`--foo`".

`git rev-parse` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a1f91cfd9633a4f59e0534fa5ba076e031a78ed/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L112-L115):

> Note that if you are verifying a name from an untrusted source, it is
> wise to use `--end-of-options` so that the name argument is not mistaken
> for another option.
>
> ```
> $ git rev-parse --verify --end-of-options $REV^{commit}
> $ git rev-parse --default master --verify --end-of-options $REV
> ```

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git mktag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c7d6d419b0ddbc895aaf5de81a79a10773842d89/Documentation/git-mktag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktag))</sup> validates its input using its own rules before writing a tag object---it has been updated to share the logic with `git fsck`".

That means it also supports `--end-of-options`.

See [commit 06ce791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06ce79152be8dab44b63faf4486d5c5c171434af) (06 Jan 2021), [commit 2aa9425](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2aa9425fbeb58f459240f223525e512499ab62e4), [commit 3f390a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f390a366cc4a083b11452b899a04416aea00bdd), [commit 9a1a3a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a1a3a4d4c5648b94dbe8f34b83271d96dbaa6ec), [commit acfc013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acfc01332bc477e19b8af6b5002c0b962fde3326), [commit 1f3299f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f3299fda9d0800d8e882540d36e4d78797e998e), [commit acf9de4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acf9de4c94e0de260f962dc04cc4f9007cedbf1a), [commit 40ef015](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40ef015a2711ef603ab712e0a6882e24e980ef6d), [commit dfe3948](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfe39487284af223737c58dd830261c2995f4fba), [commit 0c43911](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c439117bbc8f51b9c13b323ea7a9f76892a433d), [commit 692654d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/692654dca01dda9951a81de4ecfa958b61b8bc5c), [commit 30f882c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30f882c16d64e9859d823db16ae7c5157f09397b), [commit ca9a1ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca9a1ed969f09c8b6efc3e1d925ac1bda7370886), [commit 47c95e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47c95e77d158e4660dab25b9fdd6f4d70013b430), [commit 3b9e4dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b9e4dd3a3be6d39bece6a9272640be3b5a817d2), [commit 5c2303e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c2303e0c7a981528dae68d4979d3bfdc2526276), [commit 317c176](https://github.com/git/git/commit/317c1762798f9e1ee0cb8096a2071561a8bb1fdc), [commit 0d35ccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d35ccb5e07662ed95775ed2e59eec4026f67931), [commit b5ca549](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5ca549c932a2818869dba7cc7c60a8ec5946a8d), [commit aba5377](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aba5377f693df650879a23ae549ca458ff116965), [commit 18430ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18430ed363f469d5fe6e143857b7fe72aca807ba) (05 Jan 2021), and [commit 9ce0fc3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ce0fc33118892a22841f474ed239b512346c83a), [commit f59b61d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f59b61dc4d0bb4e5e3bc8c48894ad346ece8cdbe) (23 Dec 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7d6d41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7d6d419b0ddbc895aaf5de81a79a10773842d89), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`mktag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f390a366cc4a083b11452b899a04416aea00bdd): convert to parse-options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Convert the "`mktag`" command to use [`parse-options.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3f390a366cc4a083b11452b899a04416aea00bdd/parse-options.h) instead of its own ad-hoc argc handling.
> This doesn't matter much in practice since it doesn't support any options, but removes another special-case in our codebase, and makes it easier to add options to it in the future.
>
> It does marginally improve the situation for programs that want to execute git commands in a consistent manner and e.g. always use `--end-of-options`.
> E.g.
> "`gitaly`" does that, and has a blacklist of built-ins that don't support `--end-of-options`.
> This is one less special case for it and other similar programs to support.

---

Before Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "`git $cmd --end-of-options --rev -- --path` for some `$cmd` failed to interpret `--rev` as a rev, and "`--path`" as a path.
This was fixed for many programs like "`reset`" and "`checkout`".

See [commit 9385174](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9385174627cbb7301b1007912514a66b75d78f31) (06 Dec 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9eec6a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eec6a1c5fc03e5f01f200bdb28f1dc6b8e9f03e), 20 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`parse-options`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9385174627cbb7301b1007912514a66b75d78f31): decouple "`--end-of-options`" and "`--`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When we added generic end-of-options support in [51b4594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51b4594b4024d5cb2b4ace36ff932affa31c03f4) ("`parse-options`: allow `--end-of-options` as a synonym for --", 2019-08-06, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a12f89865236789b5723277bb6809e92ce68f54) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1d4a28250629ae469fc5dd59ab843cb2fd68e12)), we made them true synonyms.
> They both stop option parsing, and they are both returned in the resulting argv if the `KEEP_DASHDASH` flag is used.
>
> The hope was that this would work for all callers:
>
> - most generic callers would not pass `KEEP_DASHDASH,` and so would just do the right thing (stop parsing there) without needing to know anything more.
> - callers with `KEEP_DASHDASH` were generally going to rely on `setup_revisions()`, which knew to handle `--end-of-options` specially
>
> But that turned out miss quite a few cases that pass `KEEP_DASHDASH` but do their own manual parsing.
> For example, "[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9385174627cbb7301b1007912514a66b75d78f31/Documentation/git-reset.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup>, "[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9385174627cbb7301b1007912514a66b75d78f31/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup>, and so on want pass `KEEP_DASHDASH` so they can support:
>
> ```
> git reset $revs -- $paths
> ```
>
> but of course aren't going to actually do a traversal, so they don't call `setup_revisions()`.
> And those cases currently get confused by `--end-of-options` being left in place, like:
>
> ```
> $ git reset --end-of-options HEAD
> fatal: option '--end-of-options' must come before non-option arguments
> ```
>
> We could teach each of these callers to handle the leftover option explicitly.
> But let's try to be a bit more clever and see if we can solve it centrally in [`parse-options.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9385174627cbb7301b1007912514a66b75d78f31/parse-options.c).
>
> The bogus assumption here is that `KEEP_DASHDASH` tells us the caller wants to see `--end-of-options` in the result.
> But really, the callers which need to know that `--end-of-options` was reached are those that may potentially parse more options from argv.
> In other words, those that pass the `KEEP_UNKNOWN_OPT` flag.
>
> If such a caller is aware of `--end-of-options` (e.g., because they call `setup_revisions()` with the result), then this will continue to do the right thing, treating anything after `--end-of-options` as a non-option.
>
> And if the caller is not aware of `--end-of-options`, they are better off keeping it intact, because either:
>
> 1. They are just passing the options along to somebody else anyway, in which case that somebody would need to know about the `--end-of-options` marker.
> 2. They are going to parse the remainder themselves, at which point choking on `--end-of-options` is much better than having it silently removed.
>    The point is to avoid option injection from untrusted command line arguments, and bailing is better than quietly treating the untrusted argument as an option.
>
> Note that this does shut the door for callers which want to know if we hit end-of-options, but don't otherwise need to keep unknown opts.
> The obvious thing here is feeding it to the DWIM `verify_filename()` machinery.
> And indeed, this is a problem even for commands which do understand `--end-of-options` already.
> For example, without this patch, you get:
>
> ```
> $ git log --end-of-options --foo
> fatal: option '--foo' must come before non-option arguments
> ```
>
> because we refuse to accept "`--foo`" as a filename (because it starts with a dash) even though we could know that we saw end-of-options.
> The `verify_filename()` function simply doesn't accept this extra information.
>
> So that is the status quo, and this patch doubles down further on that.
> Commands like "`git reset`" have the same problem, but they won't even know that parse-options saw `--end-of-options`! So even if we fixed `verify_filename()`, they wouldn't have anything to pass to it.
>
> But in practice I don't think this is a big deal.
> If you are being careful enough to use `--end-of-options`, then you should also be using "`--`" to disambiguate and avoid the DWIM behavior in the first place.
> In other words, doing:
>
> ```
> git log --end-of-options --this-is-a-rev -- --this-is-a-path
> ```
>
> works correctly, and will continue to do so.
> And likewise, with this patch now:
>
> ```
> git reset --end-of-options --this-is-a-rev -- --this-is-a-path
> ```
>
> will work, as well.

Comment: +1: Thanks for this far-more-than-we-thought-we-needed-to-know compendium about Git options parsing. For me, all this it boils down to: "better not use `--foo` as a branch, tag or filename". But it's nice to be able to write robust scripts that could deal with such repos safely.