# Git - list all authors of a folder of files?

Tags: git

How can I list the author names of a particular folder that's versioned by git?

I see that I can `git blame` a file and list the author of each line, but I can't do that for a folder, and I would also like only a unique list (each author listed only once)

Comment: I think you should write a shell script to do that, with for-loop, pipe, grep, sort, uniq, etc. Also, git blame won't show all the authors but just the last-modifiers, I think you should do that with git log.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Actually, there is a native Git command for that, [`git shortlog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog):

```
git shortlog -n -s -- myfolder
```

The options do:

- Option `-s` just shows the number of commits per contributor. Without it, the command lists the individual commits per author.
- Option `-n` sorts the authors by number of commits (descending order) instead of alphabetical.

###### Illustrative output example

```
ojdo@machine:someRepo$ git shortlog -n -s -- myFolder
    37  John Doe
    31  Eager Contributor
    11  Jane Doe
    10  Pipeline Fixer
     5  Docs Specialist
```

And in case you encounter "duplicate" entries, use a [`.mailmap` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap) to group multiple entries to the same contributor. This is much saner than trying to rewrite the whole history of a repo, although there is [a Q&A for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27275187/2375855), too.

---

###### What is `--` good for?

And just in case you have not encountered a loose `--` in a git command yet: it is a separator option to mark that what follows cannot be a `<revspec>` (range of commits), but only a `<pathspec>` (file and folder names). That means: if you would omit the `--` and by accident had a branch or tag named *myfolder*, the command `git shortlog -n -s myfolder` would **not filter for the directory** *myfolder*, but instead **filter for history of branch or tag** "myfolder". This separator is therefore useful (and necessary) in a number of git commands, like `log` or `checkout`, whenever you want to be clear whether what you specify is either a revision (commmit, branch, tag) or a path (folder or file name). And of course, this site already [has a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22750028/2375855) on this.

Comment: What does `--` do?

Comment: `git shortlog` accepts a `<revision range>` argument. If `myfolder` by accident would be the name of a tag or branch, the shortlog would be limited to that label's commit history. The separator `--` is used by many git commands to specify that what follows may only ever be a file or directory name (a path specification), no command or revision.

Comment: @AaronFranke thanks for asking; now I also incorporated the `--` part directly in the answer and linked to the canonical question on SO.

Answer (score 26):

Based on [The shortest possible output from git log containing author and date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441010/the-shortest-possible-output-from-git-log-containing-author-and-date)

do this

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an%x09" myfolder | sort | uniq
```

Comment: I found this more reliable: `git log --pretty=format:"%an%x09" myfolder | sort | uniq -c | sort -t ' '  -k 1 -r`

Comment: folder or file .

Comment: I think this answer is now suboptimal when looking at `git shortlog` below. The right answer should be that other one.

Answer (score 3):

If you want only the list of authors of a repository:

`git ls-files | xargs -n1 git blame --line-porcelain | sed -n
's/^author //p' | sort -d | uniq`

If you want to do it for a file order by the number of lines of code contributions it is simple:

`git blame --line-porcelain "_MY_FILE_" | sed -n 's/author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

If you want to do it for the whole repository also ordered by code contributions:

`git ls-files | xargs -n1 git blame --line-porcelain | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nr`

Comment: Very useful  `git blame --line-porcelain`. A relief for unix philosophy with `| grep author`