# How to get all the authors of a group of files in Git?

Tags: git, git-blame

I'd like some help from the git blame/bash/awk gurus. I want to get a list all the people, who appear in the git blame of each file in a particular group of files. Example:

- files A and B;
- git blame lists John, Terry, and Merry as authors of various lines in A;
- git blame lists Jane and Mike as authors of various lines in B;
- the command takes as input files A and B and returns Jane, John, Terry, Merry, and Mike.

So my idea is this:

- I finish my work on a branch;
- execute the command, which take as input all the files, that were modified on this branch compared to master and returns a list of all the authors of lines in these files.

The idea is to know who to ping of a review.

Comment: [`git shortlog -n -s -- file1 file2…`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49275435/7976758); see also other answers there. Also search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+author+file

Answer (score 1):

You could use `log` then pipe to `sort`

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%an" -- path/to/fileA path/to/fileB | sort -u
```

If you want an alias for that, go for

```
git config --global alias.who '!f() { git log --all --pretty=format:"%aN" -- $1 | sort -u; }; f'

# then just
git who "path/to/fileA path/to/fileB"
```

Answer (score 0):

To list the authors of all the lines in a file whose path is `$path`.

```
git blame --porcelain -- $path | sed -n -e '/^author /s/^author //p' | uniq -u
```

To deal with a group of files, like A and B,

```
for path in A B;do
    git blame --porcelain -- $path
done | sed -n -e '/^author /s/^author //p' | uniq -u
```