# Add all files using git add except one directory

Tags: git

I am trying to add all the files to my git index using

```
git add -A
```

However, there is one directory with very large files that is causing this error:

```
fatal: confused by unstable object source data for 9f8c02a8d2a04d7fffed08b299a0cb8996ab7ecb
```

Therefore, the adding process is broken! How can I tell git I want to exclude this directory while adding everything else? Available online solutions first add everything and then remove some files. Obviously, I cannot do this because git crashes while adding the files in that specific directory.

Comment: why not simply "git-add -A dir1 dir2 dir3 etc." but not giving the one you don't want? Else use `gitignore`.

Comment: please never ever (neither if you know what you're doing) add all files, this is (for reasons) bad practice

Comment: @NicoAlbers what should I do instead? Selecting one by one? Can I at least add a whole directory?

Comment: Yeah, best practice would be adding one by one and having a look on the diff for each file. This is easier with some graphical tools but works fine on the command line too. When adding all the risk is too high that you commit files you didn't want to commit (sensitive data, not ready versions, etc...). At least you should have a look before committing (`git status`) and never use `git commit -a`

Comment: @NicoAlbers Maybe a best practice, but if you've checked `git status` I think it's fine to do `git add .`, it's  more efficient than manually adding files/folders.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If your Git version is new enough,

```
git add -- . ':!<path>'
```

`.` means all under the current directory, and `':!<path>'` means to exclude the path. So it means to add all except `path`.

The term for `. ':!<path>'` is [pathspec](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec). However, the doc is a bit obscure and lack of abundant examples. I find [this post](https://css-tricks.com/git-pathspecs-and-how-to-use-them/) very helpful to understand `pathspec`.

Comment: Here is what I entered: git add -- . ':!aggregated-data'
And here is what I got: fatal: pathspec 'aggregated-data/user70b596ed89eccbe1/:!aggregated-data' did not match any files

Comment: @Moh What's your Git version?

Comment: Ops I was in the wrong directory. In the depo's root directory I get this message: fatal: pathspec ':!aggregated-data/' did not match any files

The version is 1.7.1

Comment: @Moh 1.7.1 is too old to support this feature. Try `ls -1 | grep -v ^aggregated-data/$ | xargs -i git add {}` under the repo's root instead, if you are using `git-bash` or *nix.

Comment: this worked for me, but with bit modified version of this `git add -- . :!<path>` hope it helps someone

Comment: This worked for me on `git version` **2.31.1.windows.1** and I was able to exclude a handful of files from the commit like so: `git add -- . ':!file1' ':!file2' ':!file3'`.

Comment: What does `--` mean? I usually add by using `git add .` is `--` required?

Comment: @Anatoly More info on "--" here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878332/2596132 In general, it appears to mean "end of options". Also, it is completely optional here.

Answer (score 8):

On my windows system, the following worked:

```
git add -- . :!"path_to_folder"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: for excluding multiple folders : `git add -- . :!"path_to_folder1" :!"path_to_folder2"`

Answer (score 4):

@ElpieKay's answer didn't work for me, but this one did:

```
git add -- . :!<path>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Alec you should add (')single quotes to the `:!<path>`

this

```
:!<path>
```

into this

```
':!<path>'
```

Example

```
> git add -- . ':!somefolder'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way this is more flexible is adding all of your files, then try to exclude one by one, based on your desire.
For example, in my Laravel project I would like to deselect the `dist` and `plugins` folder in `public` folder

```
1)git add .
2) git reset -- public/dist
3)git reset -- public/plugins
```

Consequently, as I wrote `git status`, the below picture shows the result of codes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an added bonus, dont' forget you can use glob patterns to further refine what is excluded :

```
git add . -- ':!somefolder' ':!**/some_deep_nested_folder/*'
```

As mentioned in the [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) git glossary