# What parameter to add to the git add * command to make it ignore certain files or folders?

Tags: git, github

This question will be brief. When I use the `git add *` command so that my git index takes into account the new additions, this indexes all the files contained in the folder of the specified path. The problem is that even those contained in the `.gitignore` file are indexed. I would like to know if there is a parameter to add to the `git add *` command to specify which folders or files to ignore. I work on Windows 10. Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316434/add-all-files-using-git-add-except-one-directory may help.

Comment: "even those contained in the `.gitignore` file" probably indicate that some files listed in your `.gitignore` are actually already tracked. See [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

#### `find`

If you are on Linux, you could use `find` and filter out the directory as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736463/10871900)

```bash
git add ${find -not -path "./toIgnore/*" }
```

However, this assumes that no files start with `-` or contain spaces or similar.

#### Remove them afterwards

Alternatively, you could just add all files and remove the files to ignore from the staging area afterwards:

```bash
git add .
git restore --staged toIgnore
```

#### ignore them

In case you want to do this ever time, you might want to put that file into a `.gitignore` file or use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` in order to tell git to assume you haven't touched the file until it needs to do a change thereor similar.

Note that those do not need to be checked in. For example, you could create a file `exclude` in `.git/info` which acts like a `.gitignore` file but it isn't comitted. It is also possible to create `.gitignore` files in subdirectories and even ignore the `.gitignore` files themselves. See [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately I work on Windows 10. Do you know of another similar alternative working on this system? Thanks!

Comment: Only the first option is Linux/vash-specific. The other options should work on Windows as well. Aside from that, you could also try using git bash or WSL for getting the first solution to work on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Good evening!