I want to use git add and git commit for large scale projects
Ok so i have been wondering is there any way to make a command according to my desires for example
This is for large scale projects
"I want to commit/add all the files except this(files 1) this(file2) and this(file3)
I know that you can add/commit by
git add file1 file2 file3 

or
git commit file1 ...

but i want it another way around
Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475457/add-all-files-to-a-commit-except-a-single-file , https://stackoverflow.com/a/50316635/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+files+except

Does this answer your question? Add all files to a commit except a single file?

I don't have much experience with working on large projects, but in small projects, mostly I remember the name of the files which are to be excluded from commit like as you mentioned file1 file2 or file3.
So what I do is just staged all the files first and then unstaged the files which are to be excluded by running the following command
git restore --staged file1 file2 file3

Using this command you can remove the files from staging area to the unstaged area and hence prevent commit for those files for that time
