# how to remove special files from git repository

Tags: git

I have a file named `-fL` that generated by curl command in my project, now I added the `-fL` file to `.gitignore`, then I want to remove it from the git repository. I have tried to use this command:

```
git rm "-fL"
git rm '-fL'
git rm -fL
```

both of this command could not remove the file successfully, what should I to do remove it? The error may look like this:

```
error: unknown switch `L'
usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
    --sparse              allow updating entries outside of the sparse-checkout cone
    --pathspec-from-file <file>
                          read pathspec from file
    --pathspec-file-nul   with --pathspec-from-file, pathspec elements are separated with NUL character
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750028/in-git-what-does-dash-dash-mean + `git rm -- -fL`. Note that `"` and `'`  relate to how the shell interpreter interprets your commands and have nothing to do with git per se.

Comment: Write the path with the current directory as a prefix: `git rm ./-fL` this will work with *all* tools.